# Issue with saving an update information in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter, addition

My goal is to update job_contract.
There are two ways that this SHOULD be done. 1. through the client's page AND 2. through  the provider's page.

What I currently have is in my job model is:

```
 public function update_job_contract($post_obj)
{
    $id = $post_obj['id'];
    $data = array 
    (
        'client_feedback' => $post_obj['client_feedback'],
        'client_notetoself' => $post_obj['client_notetoself'],
        'contract_status' => $post_obj['contract_status'],
        'client_id' => $this->auth_model->get_user_id()
    );

    $this->db->insert('job', $data);
}

public function provider_update_job_contract($post_obj)
{
    $id = $post_obj['id'];
    $data = array 
    (
        'provider_feedback' => $post_obj['provider_feedback'],
        'provider_notetoself' => $post_obj['provider_notetoself'],
        'provider_id' => $this->auth_model->get_user_id()
    );

    $this->db->insert('job', $data);
}
```

I have the following lines in my client controller page:

```
public function update_job_contract() 
{
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3,0);


    $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id);  

    $this->load->view('client/update_job_contract', $data);
}   

public function update_job_contract_submit() 
{
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    if ( '0' == $_POST['id'] ) {
    $this->job_model->update_job_contract($_POST);
    //} 
    redirect('client/manage_job_contracts?message=Congratulations!');
}
```

And this in my provider controller page:

```
 public function provider_update_job_contract() 
{
    $this->validateRole('provider');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3,0);


    $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id);  

    $this->load->view('provider/provider_update_job_contract', $data);
}   

public function provider_update_job_contract_submit() 
{
    $this->validateRole('provider');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    if ( '0' == $_POST['id'] ) {
    $this->job_model->provider_update_job_contract($_POST);
    } 
    redirect('provider/job_contracts?message=Congratulations!');
}
```

Problem is, they don't really update the entries. Please help..

Comment: what is $post_obj ? is that defined somewhere else? if not take a look at the codeigniter tutorial for form to db basics  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.  public function update_job_contract($obj)
   {
  $id = $obj['id'];
  $data = array 
  (
   'client_feedback' => $obj['client_feedback'],
   'client_notetoself' => $obj['client_notetoself'],
   'contract_status' => $obj['contract_status'],
   'client_id' => $this->auth_model->get_user_id()
  );
  
  $this->db->insert('job', $data);
   } still does not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$this->db->insert()`, but with Active Record to update the row you should be using `$this->db->update()`

```
$data = array(
   'title' => $title,
   'name' => $name,
   'date' => $date
);

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Another words your functions should look like this:

```
public function update_job_contract($post_obj)
{
    $id = $post_obj['id'];
    $data = array 
    (
        'client_feedback' => $post_obj['client_feedback'],
        'client_notetoself' => $post_obj['client_notetoself'],
        'contract_status' => $post_obj['contract_status'],
        'client_id' => $this->auth_model->get_user_id()
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('job', $data);
}

public function provider_update_job_contract($post_obj)
{
    $id = $post_obj['id'];
    $data = array 
    (
        'provider_feedback' => $post_obj['provider_feedback'],
        'provider_notetoself' => $post_obj['provider_notetoself'],
        'provider_id' => $this->auth_model->get_user_id()
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('job', $data);
}
```

Also, inside the controllers $_POST should be replaced with $this->input->post()

Using this one as example:

```
public function provider_update_job_contract_submit() 
{
    $this->validateRole('provider');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $post = $this->input->post();
    if ( '0' == $post['id'] )
    {
        $this->job_model->provider_update_job_contract($post);
    } 
    redirect('provider/job_contracts?message=Congratulations!');
}
```

Make sure you update other controllers in the same way

Comment: what do you mean nothing is changing or adding to db? for these particular fields, nothing else.. only this part is responsible for this..

Comment: Ok, this is a bit silly but I guess you're actually providing different data for update? When the data will be the same as already stored in database, mysql won't return true on update, it will be ignored as nothing actually changed. I guess that's not the case?

Comment: try inside the model <?php print_r($post_obj); ?>. does it include your $_POST data? it this the content you're expecting?

Comment: for client, he uses update_job_contract() while provider  uses provider_update_job_contract()

Comment: you mean echo "<pre>";
  print_r($post_obj); 
  exit; inside update_job_contract? it did not show anything...

Comment: ok, it doesn't even go there (to the model). is this part of your controller intentional if ( '0' == $_POST['id'] ) ? should the $_POST['id'] equal ZERO? Can you do print_r($_POST) inside your controller at the top, what's the output?

Comment: I put <?echo "<pre>";
  print_r($post_obj); ?> inside update_job_contract view page and here's the error I got: Severity: Notice


Message:  Undefined variable: post_obj


Filename: client/update_job_contract.php


Line Number: 85 .... line 85 is print_r($post_obj); ?>

Comment: i just tried printing ($_POST)  also got same error 
Severity: Notice


Message:  Undefined variable: post_obj


Filename: client/update_job_contract.php


Line Number: 85

Comment: So are you POSTing anything to the controller? Seems like nothing is passed from $_POST array. So.. you either do (inside the controller) global $_POST; or you refer to its values as $this->input->post();

Comment: i did this: public function update_job_contract($post_obj)
   {
  $id = $post_obj['id'];
  
  $data = array 
  (
   'client_feedback' => $this->input->post('client_feedback'),
   'client_notetoself' => $this->input->post('client_notetoself'),
   'contract_status' => $this->input->post('contract_status'),
   'client_id' => $this->auth_model->get_user_id()
  );
  
  $this->db->from('job')->where('id',$id);
  if ($this->db->count_all_results() == 0) 
  { 
   $this->db->insert('job', $data);
  } else

   $this->db->update('job', $data);
   } got   Undefined variable: post_obj

Comment: You are still referring to it in the first line ($id = $post_obj['id']), try $id = $this->input->post('id');

Comment: to be honest, you should leave your models as they are, and update controllers to pass $this->input->post() to the model method, but firstly let's track the error down and then you can polish the code out

Comment: no change..still the same as the very first result :((

Comment: I added new columns to job table to give way to another function I could already do in the db.. but the problem is about this update..

Comment: client_feedback, provider_feedback, client_notetoself, provider_notetoself, contract_status are all empty at start.. they will just have values after update_job_contract and provider_update_job_contract are sucessfully done..

Comment: are you able to update the table with pure mysql? maybe this mysql user doesn't have permission to perform update? Other models (updates) work?

Comment: yes, this for ex, works properly  public function edit_job_submit() 
 {
  $this->validateRole('client');
  $this->load->model('job_model');
  
  if ( '0' != $_POST['id'] ) 
  {
   $this->job_model->edit_job($_POST);
  } else {
   $this->job_model->add_job($_POST);
  }
  redirect('client/manage_jobs?message=Job updated.');
 }

Comment: its model code is public function edit_job($obj)
 {
  //allows client to edit/update his job details
  $id = $obj['id'];
  
   $data = array
  (
   'title' => $obj['title'],
   'description' => $obj['description'],
   'start_date' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($obj['start_date'])),
   'category_id' => $obj['category_id']
  );
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $this->db->update('job', $data);    
 }

Comment: Have you already tried to remove "if ( '0' == $_POST['id'] )" inside your "provider_update_job_contract_submit()" controller? The $_POST['id'] is probably not set, so it wont go inside this statement...

Comment: ha! I will leave it with you then, you should modify your controllers to replace $_POST with $this->input->post() everywhere. Phew... that was long conversation but it payed off, we fixed the bug mate! ; )